# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^k}{a^x} = 0\ (a>1,k>0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^k}{a^x} = 0\ (a>1,k>0)$.

P.S. This problem comes from my analysis book. You may use the definition of limits or invoke the Heine theorem for help. *It means the proof should only use some basic properties and definition of limits rather than more complicated approaches.*

Comment: Are you allowed l'Hopital's rule? If so, apply that $k$ times to get a constant over something going to infinity.

Comment: @Clayton Sorry, but that rule is not allowed here. > <

Answer (score 2):

Applying the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214001/what-are-common-methods-techniques-can-be-used-to-prove-that-limit-of-an-infinit/214014#214014)

**Theorem**: If ${a_n}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= a\,,$ then

1) if $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n =0 \,,$

2) if $ a>1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n| =\infty \,,$

, we have, let $b_x=\frac{x^k}{a^x}$, then

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{b_{x+1}}{b_x}=  \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(x+1)^k}{a^{x+1}}\frac{a^x}{x^k} = \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{a}(1+\frac{1}{x})^k = \frac{1}{a} < 1, $$

which implies by part $(1)$ of the theorem that $\lim_{x \to \infty}b_x=0. $

Comment: Note that x is not necessarily a integer. You've just proved it in sequence situation.

Answer (score 1):

$$x>0:$$

$$\frac{a^x}{x^k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\ln a)^n}{x^kn!}$$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\;=\frac{1}{x^k}+\frac{\ln a}{x^{k-1}}+\cdots+\frac{(\ln a)^k}{k!}+\frac{x(\ln a)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}+\cdots$$

$$\;>\frac{x(\ln a)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

$$\Rightarrow0<\frac{x^k}{a^x}<\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{(k+1)!}{(\ln a)^{k+1}}$$

$$\text{etc.}$$

Comment: You're right. But this problem expects some kind of way that use basic properties and definition of limits.

Comment: @ymfoi It would be best if you defined what you mean by *basic* then. Are you trying to use $\epsilon-\delta$? If so, you can apply it to the RHS in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what is allowed. Let $x^k=y$. We are then looking at $\frac{x}{(a^{1/k})^y}$.

Let $a^{1/k}=b$. We are computing the simpler-looking $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{b^y}$.

Assume that we know that $b^y$ is increasing. Let $b=1+d$.

Then $(1+d)^y \ge (1+d)^{\lfloor y\rfloor}$. But by the Binomial Theorem, $(1+d)^{\lfloor y\rfloor} \gt d^2\frac{\lfloor y\rfloor(\lfloor y\rfloor-1)}{2}$. This shows that $b^y$ grows sufficiently faster than $y$.